# How can the Airy's equation $y'' - xy = 0$ be used to model diffraction of light?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

*Differential Equations with Boundary-Value Problems by Dennis G. Zill, Michael R. Cullen* states that the equation is used to model diffraction of light. It doesn't explain how, it just goes on to solve it using a series solution.

Has anyone any idea how it is used or has any references? Or if anyone knows any other applications of this equation then that would be interesting also :)

Comment: A survey of other physical applications of Airy equation can be found at: http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.16 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reference to a 1977 article by H. M. Nussenzveig in Scientific American about the [Theory of the Rainbow](http://www.phys.uwosh.edu/rioux/genphysII/pdf/rainbows.pdf).  The captions of the figures in the article are informative.

The differential equation also appears in Professor Nussenzveig's 1992 book *Diffraction Effects in Semiclassical Scattering*.